# React elements and fat arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In the Redux examples, the syntax used is:

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <AddTodo />
    <VisibleTodoList />
    <Footer />
  </div>
)
```

I was toying around with a new example app and mistyped the above code with curly brackets instead of parentheses like so:

```
const App = () => {
  <div>
    <AddTodo />
    <VisibleTodoList />
    <Footer />
  </div>
}
```

I console logged both of the following and the result seemed to be the same. My question is what is the difference between these 2 and why does React like the parentheses but not the curly brackets?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Your first example is more or less equivalent to:

```
var App = function() { return <div>...</div>; };
```

Your second is more or less equivalent to:

```
var App = function() { <div>...</div>; };
```

React is probably complaining that nothing is being returned in the second example.

**Slightly Longer Version**

Let's take React out of the equation. In es6 you can create a fat arrow function like this:

```
const getWord = () => {
  return 'unicorn';
}
```

And we're given a shortcut to do the same thing with less code:

```
const getWord = () => 'unicorn';
```

`unicorn` is returned even though you don't ever explicitly type `return` anywhere.

In your first example, you wrapped your JSX in parenthesis. The equivalent in our simple example is:

```
const getWord = () => ('unicorn');
```

or this

```
const getWord = () => (
  'unicorn'
);
```

The last four examples are equivalent. Hope that helps!

Comment: That helps a lot. Thanks. I took a look at the
[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) after reading your response and it makes a lot more sense now.