# Mapping an array inside of a react component after importing arrray from file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react component. I also have a js file that has an array of objects which is imported into the component. I want to use the `.map()` function on the array and display each piece of information inside `li` whic is currently inside of the `ul` that wraps around it. I know the Activity is imported correctly because `console.log(Activity)` is displaying the 5 items. When it gets to the map function, it is deciding not to iterate and display any of the infromation. I looked at the source code and it just shows an empty unordered list.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Activities from '../../../../fakedata/fake_activity';

export default function Activity(props){
    console.log(Activities)
    return(
        <div className="activity-container">
            <ul className="activity-list">
                {
                    Activities.map((activity) => {
                        <li className="activity">
                            <span className="activity-group">{activity.group}</span>
                            <span className="activity-date">{activity.date}</span>
                            <span className="activity-description">{activity.description}</span>
                        </li>
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

this is the activity object being imported

```
const activity = [
    {
        group: 'Homiez',
        description: '',
        date: '3:22 pm 1/15'
    },
    {
        group: 'Bros',
        description: '',
        date: '1:48 pm 1/15'
    },
    {
        group: 'Bros',
        description: '',
        date: '12:31 pm 1/15'
    },
    {
        group: 'Homiez',
        description: '',
        date: '10:13 am 1/15'
    },
    {
        group: 'Manayek',
        description: '',
        date: '7:17 pm 1/14'
    },
]

module.exports = activity;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning anything from inside your `map` function. You either need to change it to be like this:

```
Activities.map((activity) => {
  return (
    <li className="activity">
      <span className="activity-group">{activity.group}</span>
      <span className="activity-date">{activity.date}</span>
      <span className="activity-description">{activity.description}</span>
    </li>
  );
})
```

or this:

```
Activities.map((activity) => (
  <li className="activity">
    <span className="activity-group">{activity.group}</span>
    <span className="activity-date">{activity.date}</span>
    <span className="activity-description">{activity.description}</span>
  </li>
))
```

This q+a might help you understand why: [React elements and fat arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35930695/react-elements-and-fat-arrow-functions/35930759#35930759)

Comment: I always forget the stupid return statement... Thanks. Lol